# how to find out what program/process is opening internet explorer?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, virus

I have some virus or something and internet explorer keeps opening with random add sites when i'm browsing.

however, part of me wonders whether this is just some subtle way that websites i'm on make add money. I have an ad blocker, so i don't expect popups. However, I don't know if the ad blocker for chrome is actually set up to block the opening of internet explorer. is there a way to find out whether some other program is opening IE or whether a chrome tab is opening it as an advertisement?

I've uninstalled everything on my computer that could be considered even slightly unofficial and run both malwarebytes and microsoft security essentials and come up clean on viruses, so I'm really stumped as to what's going on.

Comment: If IE keeps opening while you're browsing with Chrome that is very odd.  I would suggest running Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).  If it happens you can see the Process Tree to at least find out which process is the parent of Iexplore.exe.  You will also have access to all the data to understand how it was launched.

Comment: thank you found the process and killed it. not sure why virus scanners don't detect it. guess it looks too much like a normal program.